# VB6 handle DropUp (CBN_CLOSEUP or DropDownClosed in .NET) event

Tags: vb6

I have a simple ComboBox control in my VB6 Form based App and I need to listen for a DropUp (CBN_CLOSEUP) event which I cannot find it in the list of the available events. Btw, there is a DropDown event.

Comment: That property is only available in VB.NET - if you listen for LostFocus event does that have the same effect of combobox dropping up?

Comment: When close the DropDown list via ESC, or using Enter, the focus is still on the ComboBox.

Moreover the focus is still on the combobox even if I click somewhere esle via the mouse. The focus is lost on the second click

Comment: There is no built in event, you will need to subclass the control and listen for that message.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your comment. Can you give me a hint how to do that in VB6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSDN states [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), CBN_CLOSEUP is...

> Sent when the list box of a combo box has been closed. The parent
>   window of the combo box receives this notification code through the
>   WM_COMMAND message.

So the solution here is to subclass **the parent window** and listen for a WM_COMMAND message where lParam is the window handle of the combo box and CBN_CLOSEUP is the HIWORD of wParam.

IMHO one of the best examples of subclassing is [this one](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?787945-VB6-Subclassing-With-Common-Controls-Library) from LaVolpe which is just a matter of copy-and-paste in every classic VB6 projects.

After that, add following declarations:

```
Public Const CBN_CLOSEUP = &H8
Public Const WM_COMMAND = &H111
```

In the Forms where your combo boxes resides:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    SubclassWindow Me.hWnd, Me, Me.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Terminate()
    UnsubclassWindow -1&, Me
End Sub
```

This is how the ProcessMessages function should looks like:

```
Private Function ISubclassEvent_ProcessMessage(ByVal Key As String, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Message As Long, wParam As Long, lParam As Long, Action As enumSubclassActions, WantReturnMsg As Boolean, ByVal ReturnValue As Long) As Long        
    Dim wmHwnd As Long, wmId As Long, vmEvent As Long
    Select Case Message
        Case WM_COMMAND
            wmHwnd = lParam
            wmId = wParam And &HFFFF& 'LOWORD
            vmEvent = wParam \ &H10000 And &HFFFF& 'HIWORD
            If CBN_CLOSEUP = vmEvent Then
                ' Do something after a combobox closes up
                FindMyComboBox wmHwnd
            End If
    End Select
End Function
```

Now, is also possible to get the VB Control instance back from the received hWnd and do whatever you want, access Text property, ListIndex and so on, in the conventional way:

```
Private Sub FindMyComboBox(ByVal hWnd As Long)
    Dim Ctrl As Control, Combo As ComboBox
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is ComboBox Then
            If Ctrl.hWnd = hWnd Then
                If TypeName(Me.Controls(Ctrl.Name)) = "Object" Then
                    Set Combo = Me.Controls(Ctrl.Name)(Ctrl.Index)
                    List1.AddItem "CBN_CLOSEUP for " & Combo.Name & "[" & Combo.Index & "]"
                Else
                    Set Combo = Me.Controls(Ctrl.Name)
                    List1.AddItem "CBN_CLOSEUP for " & Combo.Name
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I used another very simple approach to solve the problem - check the CBO state on timer. But what you've proposed will is actually the answer of my question so

Comment: ... So thanks it might be helpful in a future if I don't have a chance to get rid off VB6. I knew that there should be a way of getting the address of WndProc and then listening for CBN_CLOSEUP event, but also the OnTImer approach works fine till now.

Here is what I did:

Private sub m_comboBox_DropDown()
      WinAPI.StartTimer Me, 50
end Sub

Public sub OnTImer()
  ...  IsDropperDown  ...
end sub

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to put your code in the `LostFocus` event of the combo box.  I would use a modular variable to keep track of if the drop down list is visible so when lost focus is fired we can determine whether or not the list was closed.

```
Private mComboDroppedDown As Boolean

Private Sub Combo1_DropDown()
    mComboDroppedDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_LostFocus()
    If mComboDroppedDown = True Then
        mComboDroppedDown = False
        Debug.Print "Combo box closed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And what if I close the dropdown listbox without loosing a focus? Simply by pressing ESC, or Enter?

Comment: You can capture those events in the `KeyDown` event of the combo box.